# How can I make .tint() and .background() affect my components?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to know how can I make .tint() affect my components.

```swift
public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                // it should use the `.background()` color from outside
                .stroke(.background, lineWidth: 15)
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: CGFloat(min(progress, 1.0)))
                // it should use the `.tint()` color from outside
                .stroke(Color.accentColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15, lineCap: .round))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
        }
    }
```

I want to achieve the same syntax as this apple component. Using Color.accentColor only seems to work when I call `.accentColor()` but stays blue when I call `.tint()`. Also I have no idea how to use any kind of backgroundColor

```
ProgressView(value: 0.5)
   .tint(.red)
   .background(.green)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `tint` property on `ShapeStyle`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/tint.

It can be used like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ChildView()
            .tint(Color.green)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fill(.tint)
    }
}
```

Applied to your example:

```
Circle()
    .trim(from: 0, to: CGFloat(min(progress, 1.0)))
    .stroke(.tint, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15, lineCap: .round))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
```

Comment: What about background? I understand that it also receives a `ShapeStyle` but .background doesn't work

Comment: `background` doesn't provide a `Color` -- *any* `View` can go in `.background()`. You don't have access to that `View`

Comment: @Jalil I see that you've now updated the question -- `background` wasn't originally part of it when I wrote this answer.